# Spacing issue with extracted body content of a mail

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I extracted the body of mail to share it to another messaging platform. But spacing issue is seen after extracting. For example, if the mail ends like:

Regards

Abcde Xyz

Dir , PD

Software Corp | Mumbai

M : + 91 9876543210

The body is getting extracted like:

RegardsAbcde XyzDir , PD Software Corp | MumbaiM : + 91 9876543210

This is my code to extract the body of the mail:

```
function conVert() {
        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, function (result) {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                let htmlBody = result.value;

                // Remove the comment block from the HTML body
                let modifiedHtmlBody = htmlBody.replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g, '');

                // Temporary div element to parse the modified HTML content
                let tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
                tempDiv.innerHTML = modifiedHtmlBody;

                // Convert anchor tags to plain text, preserving the URLs as clickable links
                let anchorTags = tempDiv.getElementsByTagName('a');
                for (let i = 0; i < anchorTags.length; i++) {
                    let anchorTag = anchorTags[i];
                    let url = anchorTag.getAttribute('href');
                    anchorTag.textContent = url;
                    anchorTag.setAttribute('href', url);
                }

                // Convert the modified HTML content to plain text
                let plainTextBody = tempDiv.textContent;

                // Paste the plain text body content into the textarea with id "item-Content"
                let textarea = document.getElementById("item-Content");
                textarea.value = plainTextBody;
            }
        });
    }

   conVert();
```

Comment: In which platform you are trying this, Is it Outlook Web/ Man/Windows?
It seems like you are extracting the body content as HTML and then converting it to Plain text, we would recommend you to use coercionType as Text for Plain Text content.

Comment: I'm trying it in Outlook Web. I need to extract the body content as HTML to extract the urls inside anchor tag and preserve them.

Comment: Try using `Office.CoercionType.Text`. More details here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.coerciontype?view=common-js-preview